# Control-Break in QB64

Tags: qb64

I have been using the following code to trap control-break but I get nothing in return:

Control-Break during program execution causes the following to happen:

```
1)Invokes interrupt trap 1Bh
2)Places 00:00 into keyboard buffer
3)Sets flag 80h at memory 40:71h
```

An example to detect Control-Break (compiled):

```
DO
   X$=INKEY$
   IF X$=CHR$(0)+CHR$(0) THEN
      PRINT "*break*"
      END
   END IF
LOOP
```

Another example to detect Control-Break (compiled):

```
DEF SEG = &H40
POKE &H71, 0
DEF SEG
DO
   DEF SEG = &H40
   X = PEEK(&H71)
   DEF SEG
   IF X = 128 THEN
      PRINT "*break*"
      END
   END IF
LOOP
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Are you asking for <ctrl><break> or <ctrl><C>? 

With QB64 on modern systems is better don't use PEEK and POKE.

Comment: I am trapping ctrl-break. I can trap ctrl-c as keyscan ascii 3 easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the following code to trap ctrl-break in qb64:

```
ON TIMER(1) GOSUB breaktrap
TIMER ON
x = _EXIT ' disable break
DO
    _LIMIT 50
    x$ = INKEY$
LOOP
breaktrap:
v = _EXIT
IF v THEN
    PRINT "*break*"
    SLEEP 5
    SYSTEM
END IF
RETURN
```

Comment: On my Kali-Linux distro this code doesn't intercept both ctrl-c nor ctrl-break. In console mode ctrl-c terminates the execution of the code!

Comment: That's odd - in Win10 this code traps ctrl-break but not ctrl-c..

Comment: ctrl-c in non-console mode is trapped by inkey$. I've seen that the above code on linux, in non-console mode, intercept as break the click on th close-windows icon on the top-right of the window.

Comment: Hmm, x-close window might call ctrl-break!?

Comment: I don't think x-close invokes ctrl-break, I think that is the QB64 code that traps x-close in the same way of ctrl-break!

Comment: Strange, _exit returns 1 for x-close, 2 for ctrl-break, and 3 for both!

Answer (score 2):

I've written the code below (QB64) that intercept key-press and key-release.

On my Linux OS this programs runs, but it doesn't intercept the key-press nor the key-release of the break key.

I don't know if said behaviour is due to my OS, OS configuration or my keyboard (Logitech wireless). I think it's due to the QB64 function `_KEYHIT` behaviour.

```
PRINT "Hit Esc to exit"
DO
  _LIMIT 20
  x& = _KEYHIT

  IF x& <> x1& THEN
    IF x& < 0 THEN
      PRINT "-"; HEX$(-x&)
    ELSE
      PRINT "+"; HEX$(x&); " [";
      y& = x&
      WHILE y& > 256
        PRINT CHR$(y& MOD 256); "] [";
        y& = y& \ 256
      WEND
      PRINT CHR$(y&); "]"
    END IF
    x1& = x&
  END IF

  IF x = 27 THEN EXIT DO
LOOP
PRINT "Escape pressed."
```

Comment: This is true because ctrl-break is a hardware line whereas _keyhit is not.

Comment: _keyhit traps a lot of keys also shift, ctrl and alt. I've C code that reads all key hit, but it's a code that runs as root, I've used it to verify if my system is recognizing the break-key!